# KerasのコードをChainerに書き換えたい(LSTM Autoencoderの実装)

Tags: python, 深層学習, chainer, keras

Kerasで次のようなLSTMオートエンコーダーが実装されています。

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Input, GRU
from keras.models import Model

input_feat = Input(shape=(30, 2000))
l = GRU( 100, return_sequences=True, activation="tanh",    recurrent_activation="hard_sigmoid")(input_feat)
l = GRU(2000, return_sequences=True, activation="tanh", recurrent_activation="hard_sigmoid")(l)
model = Model(input_feat, l)
model.compile(optimizer="RMSprop", loss="mean_squared_error")

feat = np.load("feat.npy")
model.fit(feat, feat[:, ::-1, :], epochs=200, batch_size=250)
```

ここで、featは3次元配列で、feat.shape = (269, 30, 2000)　です。
このコードをChainerに書き直すために次のようなコードを書きましたが、学習結果をみるに、どこかが間違っているようです。どこに間違いがあるかわかるでしょうか。

```
import numpy as np
from chainer import Chain, Variable, optimizers
import chainer.functions as F
import chainer.links as L

class GRUAutoEncoder(Chain):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        with self.init_scope():
            self.encode = L.GRU(2000, 100)
            self.decode = L.GRU(100, 2000)

    def __call__(self, h, mode):
        if mode == "encode":
            h = F.tanh(self.encode(h))
            return h 

        if mode == "decode":
            h = F.tanh(self.decode(h))
            return h

    def reset(self):
        self.encode.reset_state()
        self.decode.reset_state()

def main():
    feat = np.load("feat.npy") #(269, 30, 2000)

    gru_autoencoder = GRUAutoEncoder()
    optimizer = optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.01).setup(gru_autoencoder)

    N = len(feat)
    batch_size = 250
    for epoch in range(200):
        index = np.random.randint(0, N-batch_size+1)
        input_feat = feat[index:index+batch_size] #(250, 30, 2000)
        #Encoding
        input_vector = np.zeros((30, batch_size, 2000), dtype="float32")
        h = []
        for i in range(frame_rate):
            input_vector[i] = input_feat[:, i, :] #(250, 1, 2000)
            tmp = Variable(input_vector[i])
            h.append(gru_autoencoder(tmp, "encode")) #(250, 100)

        #Decoding
        output_vector = []
        for i in range(frame_rate):
            tmp = h[i]
            output_vector.append(gru_autoencoder(tmp, "decode"))

        x = input_vector[0]
        t = output_vector[0]
        for i in range(len(output_vector)):
            x = F.concat((x,input_vector[i]), axis=1)
            t = F.concat((t,output_vector[i]), axis=1)

        loss = F.mean_squared_error(x, t)
        gru_autoencoder.cleargrads()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.update()
        gru_autoencoder.reset()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Kerasのコードではfit(feat, feat[:, ::-1, :])となっているので、x = input_vector[0]の直前でoutput_vector.reverse()とするべきかと思って、それで学習をさせてみましたが、やはり結果がおかしいです。

ご助言いただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

**追記1**
Motoki Satoさん、ご回答ありがとうございます。いろいろと調べましたが、上のKerasのコードをNStepGRUを使って書き直す場合は、n_layers=1にするという理解であっているでしょうか。つまり、ネットワークは

```
class GRUAutoEncoder(Chain):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    with self.init_scope():
        self.encode = L.NStepGRU(1, 2000, 100, 0)
        self.decode = L.NStepGRU(1, 100, 2000, 0)

def __call__(self, h, encode=False):
    h = F.tanh(self.encode(h))
    if encode:
        return h
    h = F.tanh(self.decode(h))
    return h

def reset(self):
    self.encode.reset_state()
    self.decode.reset_state()
```

として、学習すればよいということで間違いないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

**追記2**

追記１のネットワークを下のように学習させようとしたのですが、TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'xs'というエラーが出ますね。

```
def main():
    feat = np.load("feat.npy")
    gru_autoencoder = GRUAutoEncoder()
    optimizer = optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.01).setup(gru_autoencoder)
    N = len(feat)
    batch_size = 250
    for epoch in range(200):
        index = np.random.randint(0, N-batch_size+1)
        batch = feat[index:index+batch_size] #(250, 30, 2000)
        t = gru_autoencoder(batch)
        loss = F.mean_squared_error(batch, t)
        gru_autoencoder.cleargrads()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.update()
        gru_autoencoder.reset()
```

Comment: L.GRUではなく、 L.NStepGRUを使うべきだったのでしょうか

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/169997

Comment: どちらも私の投稿です。英語版StackOverflowにも投稿しています。https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54283704/how-to-convert-this-keras-code-to-chainer-code-lstm-autoencoder。 まだ回答はえられてません。

Comment: Inputの(30, 2000)の30と2000という数字は何に対応するのでしょうか．

Comment: この質問は(おそらく)以下のリンクと関係します．https://qiita.com/kazetof/items/046339d3ccad24e0e5f4

Comment: ありがとうございます。feat.shape = (269, 30, 2000)の30と2000です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

結論から言えば，以下のコードで動くと思います．(データローダの部分は適当に書き換えてください)

個別に疑問点があれば，コメントで聞いてください．

```
### dataset.py
from chainer.dataset import DatasetMixin

import numpy as np


class MyDataset(DatasetMixin):
    N_SAMPLES = 269
    N_TIMESERIES = 30
    N_DIMS = 2000

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = np.random.randn(self.N_SAMPLES, self.N_TIMESERIES, self.N_DIMS) \
            .astype(np.float32)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.N_SAMPLES

    def get_example(self, i):
        return self.data[i, :, :]


### model.py
import chainer
from chainer import links as L
from chainer import functions as F
from chainer.link import Chain


class MyModel(Chain):
    N_IN_CHANNEL = 2000
    N_HIDDEN_CHANNEL = 100
    N_OUT_CHANNEL = 2000

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder = L.NStepGRU(n_layers=1, in_size=self.N_IN_CHANNEL, out_size=self.N_HIDDEN_CHANNEL, dropout=0)
        self.decoder = L.NStepGRU(n_layers=1, in_size=self.N_HIDDEN_CHANNEL, out_size=self.N_OUT_CHANNEL, dropout=0)

    def to_gpu(self, device=None):
        self.encoder.to_gpu(device)
        self.decoder.to_gpu(device)

    def to_cpu(self):
        self.encoder.to_cpu()
        self.decoder.to_cpu()

    @staticmethod
    def flip_list(source_list):
        return [F.flip(source, axis=1) for source in source_list]

    def __call__(self, source_list):
        """
        .. note:
            This implementation makes use of "auto-encoding"
            by avoiding redundant copy in GPU device.
            In the typical implementation, this function should receive
            both of ``source_list`` and ``target_list``.
        """
        target_list = self.flip_list(source_list)
        _, h_list = self.encoder(hx=None, xs=source_list)
        _, predicted_list = self.decoder(hx=None, xs=h_list)
        diff_list = [F.mean_squared_error(target, predicted).reshape((1,)) for target, predicted in zip(target_list, predicted_list)]
        loss = F.sum(F.concat(diff_list, axis=0))

        chainer.report({'loss': loss}, self)

        return loss


### converter.py (referring examples/seq2seq/seq2seq.py)
from chainer.dataset import to_device


def convert(batch, device):
    """
    .. note:
        batch must be list(batch_size) of array
    """
    if device is None:
        return batch
    else:
        return [to_device(device, x) for x in batch]


### train.py
from chainer.iterators import SerialIterator
from chainer.optimizers import Adam
from chainer.training.updaters import StandardUpdater
from chainer.training.trainer import Trainer

dataset = MyDataset()

BATCH_SIZE = 32
iterator = SerialIterator(dataset, BATCH_SIZE)

model = MyModel()
optimizer = Adam()
optimizer.setup(model)

updater = StandardUpdater(iterator, optimizer, convert, device=0)
trainer = Trainer(updater, (100, 'iteration'))

from chainer.training.extensions import snapshot_object
trainer.extend(snapshot_object(model, "model_iter_{.updater.iteration}"), trigger=(10, 'iteration'))

from chainer.training.extensions import LogReport, PrintReport, ProgressBar
trainer.extend(LogReport(['epoch', 'iteration', 'main/loss'], (1, 'iteration')))
trainer.extend(PrintReport(['epoch', 'iteration', 'main/loss']), trigger=(1, 'iteration'))
trainer.extend(ProgressBar(update_interval=1))

trainer.run()
```

話はそれますが，このモデル，いろいろと問題があると思います．
例えば，timestep==0の予測について考えると，inputの0ステップ目だけをみて，inputの最終ステップを当てなきゃいけない，ということで，全然自己符号化器になっていません．

普通に考えれば，encoderの最終タイムステップの出力を，decoderの入力にするべきだと思われます．
逆に，このモデルで当てられてしまう，ということは，全ステップでinputの0ステップ目を返せばそれなりの精度になる，ということを示唆しており，深層学習が不要である，という結論が導き出されてしまうような気がします．

そもそも，元のコードからして，出力層に`tanh`がかかってるので，入力が[-1, 1]に正規化されていることが前提になっています．この性質は一般に成り立つものではないので，ちょっと微妙な気がします．

Comment: すみません，optimizerがAdamになってます．(正しくはRMSprop)

Comment: コードまで書いてくださってありがとうございます。featは各要素が-1から+1に正規化されている量なので、tanhは問題ないと思います。

>普通に考えればencoderの最終タイムステップの出力をdecoderの入力にするべき
元のKerasのコードでは最終タイム

Comment: 元のKerasのコードでは最終タイムステップの出力のみではなく、各ステップの出力をdeocderに渡しているという認識で正しいでしょうか。

Comment: > featは...問題ないと思います。 tanhは、正則化されたモデルでは、0に近い値は出されやすく、-1や1に近い値は出されにくい性質があります。元のデータは本当にそのような性質を持っていますでしょうか。
> 元の...正しいでしょうか。 はい、その通りです。return_sequences=Trueがその部分に該当します。

Comment: ありがとうございます。元のKerasのコードはbatch_size=250ですが、Yukiさんが書いてくれたコードではbatch_size=32ですね。この違いに何か意味がありますか。

Comment: ありません。私のCPU環境で快適に回る大きさに設定しただけです。

Comment: もし回答が役立ったようでしたら，解決済みフラグとupvoteをお願いします．

Answer (score 0):

L.GRUでも書けないことは無いですが、
L.NStepGRUを使うとより簡単に書けます。
`L.NStepGRU`の方がcuDNNを使う場合高速に計算ができます。

使い方は NStepLSTMと同じなので以下のURLが参考になると思います。
もし不明な点などあれば聞いて頂ければと思います。

参考: 
https://qiita.com/aonotas/items/8e38693fb517e4e90535

Comment: ありがとうございます。URLを参考にネットワークを書いて、本文を編集しました。ご確認いただければ幸いです。